# Is there a way to add a conditional statement in a JSON file for IE8?

Tags: json, svg, internet-explorer-8

I have a map which calls in a .svg file. Being that IE8 has an issue with .svg files I want to load a backup .png file.

Currently the json is set up like so:

```
{
    "mapwidth":"960",
    "mapheight":"600",
    "levels":[
        {
            "id":"usa",
            "title":"United States",
            "map":"maps/usa.svg",
            "minimap":"maps/usa-mini.jpg",
```

I thought that by simply adding a conditional statement like

> `<!--[if IE 8]> "map":"maps/usa.png", <![endif]-->`

but clearly the json file doesn't recognize that and it causes an error. Is anyone aware of a way to have a fallback image incase the .svg won't load?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to add a conditional statement in a JSON file for IE8?

JSON is a data format. It does not have conditionals because if it had support for logic, it would not be a data format anymore.

In other words, no.

---

Add a `mapFallback` property (or similar name of your choice):

```
{
    "mapwidth":"960",
    "mapheight":"600",
    "levels":[
        {
            "id":"usa",
            "title":"United States",
            "map":"maps/usa.svg",
            "mapFallback":"maps/usa.png",
            "minimap":"maps/usa-mini.jpg",
```

and use the JavaScript that processes the JSON to modify behavior for browsers that don't support SVG.

Comment: So i've added: "mapFallback":"maps/usa.png", but how do I define what mapfallback is?

Comment: In terms of - how do I know when to use "map" and when to use "mapFallback"? You could include a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that does all the feature detection for you, and then use `if (Modernizr.svg) { /* use map */} else { /* use mapFallback */}`.